# How do I prevent bold from affecting superscript?

Tags: text-formatting, libreoffice-writer

I want to write the matrix “A^-1” in a formula in LibreOffice Writer. 
“A” is a matrix and needs to be bold but the “-1” doesn't. 
The superscript is still bold even when I place the closing bracket before the caret. How do I make “A” bold and “-1” not bold?

The (not working) formula I'm using right now: `bold { func A }^-1`

Answer (score 0):

As I was writing this question I accidentally found my answer. The ` character, if placed right before the caret, will stop the bold from affecting the superscript. The corrected code is:

`` bold func A`^-1 ``